# Почему нельзя повесить обработчик событий на кнопки jcarousel

Tags: javascript, jcarousel

Почему я не могу повесить обработчик на клавиши управления карусели `jcarousel`?

```
$('.jcarousel-next').click(function(){
     alert('Hello');
});
```

Comment: смотря как ты вешаешь, если до инициализации скрипта (что скорее всего), его на тот момент просто не существует, поэтому и подписка не идет. Ну а чтобы проверить просто перед тем как ты повесишь `.click` выведи в консоль `$('.jcarousel-next')`

Comment: оо, точно спасибо))

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев опубликуйте ответ )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По всей видимости ты пытаешься повесить событие на объект, которого ещё нет в dom модели, поэтому и подписка не идет. Ну а чтобы проверить просто перед тем как ты повесишь `.click` выведи в консоль `$('.jcarousel-next')`

Comment: Все заработало спасибо, нужно было писать этот скрипт после инициализации слайдера...

Comment: пометь вопрос как решенный